# What are the 28 known galaxies?

Tags: dc, superman

In the film *Superman*, Jor-el mentions that there are "28 known galaxies".  He makes mention of Krypton not being in the Milky Way.  Is there a list of those galaxies?

Comment: By "known" does he mean known to be colonized, or is their night sky particularly bare?

Comment: @NickT It's unclear, he literally refers to them as the `28 known galaxies`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only other reference to the 28 known inhabited galaxies appear to be [these](http://smallville.wikia.com/wiki/28_galaxies) (Smallville) and [this](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Kryptonians) (DC). I don't believe that any of the other 27 (except the Milky Way) are named anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It has never been made clear, even in apocryphal information from either the scripts of the movies, or the more recent Smallville series (2001-2011) what the names of or the locations of those galaxies were, in relationship to Krypton's home galaxy or the Milky Way.

The DC franchises, as a whole, while retaining the line of text from the Donner script, have never made clear the location of Krypton in relationship to Earth, nor have they ever decided to quantify the list of worlds/galaxies the Kryptonians had relationships with.

If Krypton were within our Milky Way galaxy, there are at least 28 galaxies or more within two million light years of the Milky Way galaxy. This is a list of the closest 28 all within 2.4 million light years of the Milky Way Galaxy. With the faster than light travel Jor-El seemed capable of producing all of these galaxies are within reach of his technology.

[image]

Comment: I'm confused.  This brings up a few facts and a lot of supposition, but even after reading it through twice, I still don't see how this answers the original question.

Comment: So if you can't find it, why not just say so?  You spend so much time on every other subject that it's like you're trying to hide the fact that the answer isn't there.

Comment: I too read through it twice. I'm still confused.

Comment: That's a lot of words to say "there's no references anywhere that list in detail the 28 galaxies."

Comment: This is a great answer despite the flak from the other commenters. If one is going to assume galaxy was not misused then these satellite clouds of the milky way and Andromeda are a great way to get up to 28 in a real world comparison.  Ju

Answer (score 0):

I think it (the scripted line) was purely to infer that the Kryptonians were a significantly advanced race and they (laymen movie-watchers) should merely accept the scientific techno-babble.